# I uploaded image via JS. How do I alter in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

EDIT: I realized that because I didn't give out the full-code (I wrote a lot since it was for a final project but I just had issue with this one tiny thing), my question was a bit confusing. The answers below are excellent but I realized that when I compiled the image data from the query, I assigned it a class so I just used that to edit, drawing from the answers below to resize the image. Thank you!

I'm doing this project where we are parsing data from a query. I'm currently using the SoundCloud Stratus API to create a very rudimentary soundcloud web page.

```
$.each(data.slice(0,10), function(index, value) {
    var icon = value.artwork_url;
    if (icon == null) {
        icon = 'assets/blacksoundcloud.png'
    }
};
```

Is there any way I can edit the image blacksoundcloud.png in CSS? Specifically, I just want to edit the size of the icon image.

```html
<header>
  <img id="main-logo" src="assets/soundcloud.png">
</header>

<section class="search">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Search for a song or artist">
  <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="results-playlist"></div>
</section>

<!-- <script src=“http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js“></script> -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="startercode_HW4_skeleton.js"></script>
<script src=“http://stratus.sc/stratus.js“></script>
```

This image is not placed in my HTML. The original purpose of this image variable is to hold the image data from a query into a database. If the image does not exist, I want to replace it with this image I have on file "blacksoundcloud.png." While I can upload it into my web page, I don't know how to go about editing the size of it.

Hopefully this is enough code.

This is currently what it looks like:[image: img]

Comment: what do you mean by edit the image blacksoundcloud.png in CSS?

Comment: Yes you can. If you insert the image in the DOM tree and manage to select it with CSS, wether using class, or id...

Comment: i have no idea what that means @theAlexandrian.

Comment: @Anuresh, I want to change the size of the image that is displayed.

Comment: where is it displayed?

Comment: @jyp95 can you post ur html code?

Comment: oh it's very complicated because i'm using Stratus soundcloud API to get the data. But yeah I'll go ahead and put down the html. Let me know if you need the rest of my code.

Comment: what is `icon` in your JS? Is it a HTML `<img>` tag or is it used as css `background-image:url()`? how does the HTML look like if you add `blacksoundcloud.png`

Comment: `parent{display:inline-block;} parent  >img{width: 100%;}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understand, You are going to change the `src` of the following code if it doesn't have any image.

```
<img id="main-logo" src="assets/soundcloud.png">
```

You can fix the width and height from the CSS. You can target only the `<img>` element which have the src `assets/blacksoundcloud.png` like below.

```
img#main-logo[src="assets/blacksoundcloud.png"] {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

The above code will fix the image width and height as 100px, even if you upload the image in any size. Look at the below snippet, the original size of the image is around 336x224. You can check it out how it is look now.

```css
img#main-logo[src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/img_01.jpg"] {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="main-logo" src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/img_01.jpg">
<img id="main-logo" src="assets/testsoundcloud.png">
```

If you want to display the image in an aspect ratio then go with `max-width` or `max-height` property like below.

```
#main-logo {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

Look at the below snippet, how it is showing image and you can compare both the one and you decide which one you want to go.

```css
img#main-logo[src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/img_01.jpg"] {
  max-width:100px;
  max-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img id="main-logo" src="http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/img/sample/img_01.jpg">
<img id="main-logo" src="assets/testsoundcloud.png">
```

Comment: This is the right answer. Targeting image "src" so the image is only affected if it is the replacement image is totally the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Your question was a little difficult to understand.

If you can't edit the too-big image to be the right size (this would be ideal), I would try one of these:

```
header img {
  width: 100px !important; /* or the size you require */
  height: 100px; /* or the size you require */
}
```

or if you have to actually get rid of the original image:

```
header img {
  display: none;
}
header:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100px; /* or the size you require */
  width: 100px; /* or the size you require */
  background: url(assets/soundcloud.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the OP's question about editing an image with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), while one cannot change the actual image with CSS you may use it to transform the way an image displays, by affecting its style properties, such as its width and height.

```css
img#main-logo {
  width: 239px;
  height: 114px;
  content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw8h1.png");
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="main-logo" src="doesNotExist.png">

</header>

<section class="search">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Search for a song or artist">
  <button id="searchButton">Search</button>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="results-playlist"></div>
</section>
```

Changing the width or height of an image with CSS is fairly easy; you just need to specify values for the width and height. If you fail to provide a valid src attribute in the HTML, you formerly might have resorted to JavaScript to assign a value to the source property of the image; the CSS alone was insufficient. Now with CSS 3, you can replace an image with CSS exclusively, setting the content property to the url of the image.

Note: every element that has an id attribute set in HTML should be unique.  You can still take advantage of targeting the src attribute with CSS if for example two images have the same class, as follows:

```css
img.m-logo[src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw8h1.png"] {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

img.m-logo[src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Giant_leopard_moth_hypercompe_scribonia_3.jpg/339px-Giant_leopard_moth_hypercompe_scribonia_3.jpg"] {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 200px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<img class="m-logo" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw8h1.png">
<img class="m-logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f4/Giant_leopard_moth_hypercompe_scribonia_3.jpg/339px-Giant_leopard_moth_hypercompe_scribonia_3.jpg">
```